# Create dynamic report in Access 2003 from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, report

I have to create a report in MS Access 2003 that shows data from sql stored procedure. Stored procedure returns data in table matrix. This report will create columns at the run time as column names are not predefined. How can I

1. Call this stored procedure from the MS Access report?
2. Create columns in the report at run time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a **Pass-Through query** that calls the SP, and use that as record source for the report.
2. The usual way is to create *enough* columns in the report, and then show/hide them as you need (`.Visible` property).

Comment: Thanks, created report as you have suggested.